# Apache Mahout - How to save a Dataset Object to HDFS?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, mahout, random-forest

Last summer we had an intern write an Apache Mahout job in Java that performs a Random Forest Classification analysis on some data.  This job was created with Apache Mahout 0.7.

Now we have upgraded our environment to run Apache Mahout 0.9, and the project no longer compiles.  This is the single line that does not compile:

```
DFUtils.storeWritable(conf, datasetPath, dataset)
```

This one line is simply tyring to store a Mahout `Dataset` object onto HDFS.  In Mahout 0.7, the `Dataset` class implemented the `Hadoop.io.Writable` Interface, but in version 0.9, the `Dataset` class simply extends the `Object` class.  Because of this change, the `storeWritable()` method is throwing me an error when given a `Dataset` object as a parameter.

In my project, the `Dataset` object represents a file that describes the data our Random Forest model is trying to analyze.  It is this step if done through the command line:

```
hadoop jar mahout-core-0.9-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe -p datasets/adult.data -f datasets/adult.data.info -d N C N C N 5 C 3 N C L
```

It is the "Generate a file descriptor for the dataset" step explained in this link:

https://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/partial-implementation.html

In summary, the line that fails above is simply trying to store the descriptor file onto HDFS.  Does anyone know the proper way to do this in Mahout 0.9?

Any suggesstions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly save it as JSON.

```
Text datasetText = new Text(dataset.toJson());
DFUtils.storeWritable(conf, datasetPath, datasetText)
```

and you can deserialize using a `fromJson` method.